# Oreo: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-8.0-oreo

my app seems to have a specific **bug with some Android 8.0 devices** on google play.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to replicate the bug myself so far.

Here is the error log:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity (ResourcesImpl.java:204)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity (Resources.java:875)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:818)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:793)
  at com.aresproductions.booksummaries.fragments.RecyclerViewAdapterBook.onBindViewHolder (RecyclerViewAdapterBook.java:188)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:6508)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:6541)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:5484)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:5750)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5589)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5585)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java:3719)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout (RecyclerView.java:3436)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout (RecyclerView.java:3988)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout (ViewPager.java:1769)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
  at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild (ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild (AppBarLayout.java:1361)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java:874)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1172)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1791)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1635)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1544)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1791)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1635)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1544)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:759)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:19692)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6057)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2515)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2224)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6834)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1039)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:851)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:742)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1025)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6809)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

So it's a **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException** inside my onBindViewHoler.

Here is my code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    BookItemViewHolder bookItemHolder = (BookItemViewHolder) holder;
    BookModel book = mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

    // Add the book item details to the book item view.
    bookItemHolder.getTextViewName().setText(book.getName());
    bookItemHolder.getTextViewAuthor().setText(book.getAuthor());
    bookItemHolder.getTextViewYear().setText(book.getYear() + "");

    // Book Covers
    int resourceId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(book.getCover(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId); //Error Here!
    bookItemHolder.getImageViewCover().setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

My book cover images are contained inside the drawable-nodpi folder.
To remind you again, this happens ONLY on some Android 8.0 devices.

Thank you

Comment: check whether your drawable in drawable-v24 folder or not if YES then move to drawable folder.

Comment: have you got the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error, but only when downloaded from google play, local apk load from Android Studio work just fine.

```
11-28 17:13:16.271 788-7441/? I/ActivityManager: START u10 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=au.com.forward.pfodAppDemo/.pfodAppDemo bnds=[297,434][579,758] (has extras)} from uid 1010035
11-28 17:13:16.294 788-913/? W/WindowManager: Token{153434f ActivityRecord{731b9ae u10 au.com.forward.pfodAppDemo/.pfodAppDemo t1000970}} failed creating starting window
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080074
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:224)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:876)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:819)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setIcon(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:322)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setIcon(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:742)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2685)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2067)
        at com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.addSplashScreen(PhoneWindowManager.java:2965)
        at com.android.server.wm.SplashScreenStartingData.createStartingSurface(SplashScreenStartingData.java:55)
        at com.android.server.wm.AppWindowContainerController.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_AppWindowContainerController_4735(AppWindowContainerController.java:145)
        at com.android.server.wm.-$Lambda$aEpJ2RCAIjecjyIIYTv6ricEwh4.$m$4(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.android.server.wm.-$Lambda$aEpJ2RCAIjecjyIIYTv6ricEwh4.run(Unknown Source:27)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

**Update - 30th Nov 2018**

I have 3 apps with the same base code.  But when this app is downloaded from Google Play it is missing its icon (which happens to be the resource ID in the error above)

Now the other two apps have icons for ALL the screen densitys, while this app only as 3 densities specified, drawable, drawable_hdpi and drawable_mdpi.
I.E. the other apps that download correctly have icons for all the densities, the above 3 plus extra ones for xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.

Perhaps Google's new resource stripping procedure is removing the icon's whose densities don't match Android 8 Nexus 3 but not leaving a default one.

Awaiting a response from Google Play to this problem.